# need to fix stdin error output in python3

Tags: python-3.x, stdin

i try to wrote a code that catch a string from stdin and write me the number of the line and it work on a small text file but it gave me an error on a larger text file.

the code:

```
import sys

def loop():
        i=1
        while True:
                for word in sys.stdin:
                        if word.strip() == 'admin':
                                print('yes')
                                print(f'the string is in line {i}')
                        i+=1
                break
loop()
```

the error:

[image]

i try to wrote a code that catch a string from stdin and write me the number of the line and it work on a small text file but it gave me an error on a larger text file.

Comment: Please post the error as text not screenshot.